# Django Models not showing in Admin.py

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have looked through the other answers extensively, but I just know this is going to turn out to be a silly oversight on my part.

I am a noob on an AWS Bitnami stack. Just trying to make  of simple model show up in my admin.

Models.py:

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
# Create your models here.



# Scrollbar ######################################################
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Marquee(models.Model):
    scrollbar_content = models.CharField(max_length = 2000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.scrollbar_content
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Marquee

admin.site.register(Marquee)
```

autodiscover() is in urls.py file

my app name is under INSTALLED APPS in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'movierec',

]
```

My PostgreSQL database is working and I have checked it through the Django shell.

Again, I'm sure I've overlooked something foolish. I hope not to waste your time.

Python 2.7 Django 1.9.7
AWS Bitnami stack

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Try `projectname.movierec` instead of `movierec` under `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't appear to be the issue. Aside from admin issue, everything runs fine with 'movie'rec'. If I change it to 'Project.movierec', I get "ImportError: No module named movierec" when I run things from the command line.

Comment: Bizarre. Is the issue happening locally or on the server?

Comment: It is happening on the server. I also ensured that I was logged in as superuser.

Comment: Try migrating, then try restarting the server. Past that, I'm stumped.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm starting to think something is strange with the bitnami stack. I changed some stuff in urls.py and though it is showing on the server's files, it does not appear to be reacting correctly "in Django", if that makes any sense. Specifically, I just added a new view and url, Django isn't seeing the url path I'm adding either.

Comment: Strange. I usually develop locally, and then deal with headaches like this all at once when it's time to deploy. :)

Comment: is your admin actualy being read. Add a deliberate syntax error in it :)

Comment: Well, I restarted Apache and now I can't access the admin. Wow. Haha. "ImportError at /admin/
No module named views"

Comment: Okay. I can't exactly explained which step fixed the issue, but I fixed it. Thank you all deeply for your time. I can see everything in the admin panel now. I think I needed to restart Apache earlier. Again, thank you.

Comment: It's not restart that you need but reload

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble.

I forgot to reload / restart apache and my changes weren't showing up.

Thank you everyone for your help!